# Как реализовать select у которого option будут в модальном окне?

Tags: jquery, select2

Есть плагин select2 для создания динамических списков и есть плагин remodal для модальных окон, возможно ли сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на селект открывалось модальное окно с option. Нужно это для такой задачи: есть сайт на котором выбираем регион, при нажатии на регион открывается модальное окно с другими регионами.

Comment: Если список с опциями формируется динамически и представляет собой див, то может проще его стилизовать как модальное окно?

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko нужна ссылка с выбором региона которая будет меняться на требуемый регион, обычным jquery это легко сделать, а вот как быть с select